# The function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, events, arguments

I've got a problem with this code. When I wrote the first code everything is ok but after processing it doesn't work. Why is it like that? I sent an event object to function as an argument so what's the problem?

Initial code:

```
var isOkej = null;
function isNumber(someValue) {
    return !isNaN(someValue);
}
window.onload = function () {
    var wykonawca = document.getElementById("informations").artist;
    var tytul = document.getElementById("informations").title;
    var label = document.getElementById("informations").label;
    var kindOftxt = document.getElementById("kindOftxt");

    var action = function (e) {
        //pokazuje unicode wpisanego znaku
        var wpisanyZnak = e.which;
        if (isNumber(this.value) || wpisanyZnak === 190) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this === wykonawca)
                kindOftxt.innerHTML = "Podaj swój Alias";
            else if (this === tytul)
                kindOftxt.innerHTML = "Podaj tytuł utworu";
            else
                kindOftxt.innerHTML = "Gdzie utwór został wydany";

            this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            isOkej = false;
        } else {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            kindOftxt.innerHTML = "";
            isOkej = true;
        }
    };
    wykonawca.onkeyup = action;
    tytul.onkeyup = action;
    label.onkeyup = action;
}
```

Final code:

```
function isNumber(someValue) {
    return !isNaN(someValue);
}
var isOkej = null;
 function action (e, wykonawca, tytul,kindOftxt) {
        //pokazuje unicode wpisanego znaku
        var wpisanyZnak = e.which;
        if (isNumber(this.value) || wpisanyZnak === 190) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this === wykonawca)
                kindOftxt.innerHTML = "Podaj swój Alias";
            else if (this === tytul)
                kindOftxt.innerHTML = "Podaj tytuł utworu";
            else
                kindOftxt.innerHTML = "Gdzie utwór został wydany";

            this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            isOkej = false;
        } else {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            kindOftxt.innerHTML = "";
            isOkej = true;
        }
    };

window.onload = function () {
    var wykonawca = document.getElementById("informations").artist;
    var tytul = document.getElementById("informations").title;
    var label = document.getElementById("informations").label;
    var kindOftxt = document.getElementById("kindOftxt"); 

    wykonawca.onkeyup = function (e) {
        action(e, wykonawca,tytul,kindOftxt);
    };    
     tytul.onkeyup = function (e) {
        action(e, wykonawca,tytul,kindOftxt);
    };    
    label.onkeyup = function (e) {
        action(e, wykonawca,tytul,kindOftxt);
    };    }
```

I really don't know what can be the reason. What do you think can be a problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem ? What is not working ? Are you getting errors ?

Comment: No errors but I mean that the field 'kindOftxt' doesn't respond to the entered informations and didn't change the color

Comment: @kamilss15 You shouldn't use isNaN to check if something is a number. The intention of the isNaN function is to determine whether or not something is the actual `NaN` value.

Comment: In 2nd case value of `this` inside function `action()` is not what you expect it to be. It doesn't refer to the element, where event occurred, anymore. Try one thing change your all  `this` to `e.currentTarget`

Comment: @EKW But in the initial code everything works. Problem is in the final code

Comment: @ArmanCharan that won't work either. the isNumber function is also supposed to return true for numeric strings.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind the events with the following code, the `this` inside `action` function is bound to the input element.

```
wykonawca.onkeyup = action;
tytul.onkeyup = action;
label.onkeyup = action;
```

When you bind the events with the updated code

```
wykonawca.onkeyup = function (e) {
    action(e, wykonawca,tytul,kindOftxt);
};    
tytul.onkeyup = function (e) {
   action(e, wykonawca,tytul,kindOftxt);
};    
label.onkeyup = function (e) {
    action(e, wykonawca,tytul,kindOftxt);
};
```

the `this` inside the anonymous event handlers is bound to the input element, but in the `action` function, `this` would refer to the global object i.e. the window object.

You can pass the `this` reference from your anonymous handlers to the `action` function as an additional argument.